# php strpos does not detect # hashtag character

Tags: php, strpos

Using php 7.1 and I have strange issue with strpos(). We have post value that needs to detect presence of # sign. 
Tried:

```
if(strpos($_POST["text"],"#")>0)
   {..} else {..}
```

and

```
if(strpos($_POST["text"],"#")!== false) 
   {..} else {..}
```

but it always go to else part. Also tried escaping hashtag

```
if(strpos($_POST["text"],"\#")>0)
```

Any idea what to do?

Hashtag is first value and I need to know is it present. Example value is:

```
$_POST["text"]='# 1010';
```

Comment: could you show us the actual value of `$_POST["text"]` for reference?

Comment: `>0` won't work if it is the first character. Other than that it should function. https://3v4l.org/fSkDo vs. https://3v4l.org/3JuXY

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. VTC for typo. https://3v4l.org/hoS51

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Value for example may be "# 1005"

Comment: @Ivan still can't reproduce the problem. https://3v4l.org/t7j8B

Comment: @Andreas here is problem https://3v4l.org/7kUhg

Comment: User already told you to not use >0.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(strpos($_POST["text"],"#")!== false)
```

should be used, not:

```
if(strpos($_POST["text"],"#")>0)
```

`#` could be the first character which is not `>0`.

Comment: It's a typo question. Just vote to close instead!